# Wrap text when knitting to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I have just knitted my red file to pdf but the code runs off of the page.

I can't seem to find a solution for it to knit the rmd file and keep all the next on the page

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of a complete rmarkdown file that showcases the problem?